# Not able to find response code for this particular site “https://www.accountonline.com/View?docId=Index&siteId=AC&langId=EN”

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-response-codes

I have the following site : "https://www.accountonline.com/View?docId=Index&siteId=AC&langId=EN" for which there is redirection.

This is code snippet --

```
String location = "https://www.accountonline.com/View?docId=Index&siteId=AC&langId=EN";
do{
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
    url = location;
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    /**
     * Setting the Browser properties
     */
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76 Safari/537.36");
    conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.connect();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Exception : {}", e.getMessage());
  }

  responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

  if ((responseCode>300 && responseCode<310)) {
        location = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        if(location==null)
            break;
  }
}while(responseCode>300 && responseCode<310);
```

I am not able to get the response code for this site. The read timeout gets over.
Not able to see the response body as well..

Comment: Get rid of the `conn.addRequestProperty` and it will work. Maybe someone else can elaborate on reason, but I just checked it on the off-chance it's the offending line, and it seems so.

Comment: yes this worked.. but what is the reason for this working properly ??

Comment: No idea, mate. Try diferent UserAgent on this site, try this User Agent on another site... this will tell you if this UserAgent string is univewrsally broken, or if just this site rejects it..

Comment: url "https://www.umpquabank.com/" gives 403 when this user agent is commented but 200 when added.

Similarly, url "http://www.express.com/" gives no response code when user agent is added, but 200 when commented.

Why is this happening ?